# How to try inline classes in Kotlin

Tags: class, kotlin, inline

It looks like inline classes are available in Kotlin since [1.2.30](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/inline-classes.md)

According to [Wasabi375](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/issues/104#issuecomment-405852817), you can enable them by:

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += ['-XXLanguage:+InlineClasses']
    }
}
```

I did that in one [project](https://github.com/elect86/kotlin-unsigned) we have, but I keep getting tons of

`Class 'unsigned.ByteKt' is compiled by a pre-release version of Kotlin and cannot be loaded by this version of the compiler`

I tried to clean & build, upgrade Gradle to 4.9, using `allprojects { }`, but nothing worked..

This is the complete [log](https://gist.github.com/elect86/41ad3d1671dbdafd41ce74f52fb39882)

How can I solve it?

Ps: note that those unsigned classes have nothing to do with the experimental unsigned from Kotlin 1.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using experimental language features like inline classes leads to the produced binaries being marked with a special pre-release flag, which renders the binaries unusable with release versions of the compiler.

In order to bypass the pre-release status check on the binaries, you can compile their usages with the flag `-Xskip-metadata-version-check`.

However, you are advised not to do so and not to use binaries compiled with unannounced pre-release language features in production, as later versions of the compiler may behave differently regarding these features.

Comment: Yeah, I'm totally aware of the risk. Anyway, I have huge expectations for inline class for a lot of actual kotlin limitations in my projects, so I'd like to start playing with them to see if they can help me. How can I add that flag?

Comment: You can add the flag in the same way as you add the language feature flag, i.e. through the `kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs` of the Kotlin compilation tasks.

Comment: Tried `freeCompilerArgs = ['-XXLanguage:+InlineClasses', '-Xskip-metadata-version-check']` and `freeCompilerArgs = ['-XXLanguage:+InlineClasses, -Xskip-metadata-version-check']`. Neither appears to work

Comment: Neither `kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs = ["-XXLanguage:+InlineClasses", "-Xskip-metadata-version-check"]`